# Jquery div from file load inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a div and inside it I have an `iframe`, the `iframe` loads a file from a URL and inside this file I show some content. My question is; is it possible to close the div from file inside `iframe` itself.

> ```
> <div id="container">
>     <iframe src="mydomain.com/index.php"></iframe>
> </div>
> ```

I know the most simple method is with jQuery to close the div, but for some reason I need to close the file load inside the `iframe` because when the session ends inside the `iframe` redirect and need to close the div called `.container`.

My question is, is it possible from mydomain.com/index.php to insert some code to close or hide the div called `.container`.

Answer (score 1):

Since they are on same domain you can access the parent window using `window.parent`

Then do something like:

```
var cont = window.parent.document.getElementById('container');
cont.style.display='none';
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/7zAnizYNdOi2ACvzUKpm?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.postMessage to communicate between the child (iframe) and the parent window.

In the iframe you can have following function;

```
function closeDivOfParent() {
    parent.postMessage("close-div","*");
}
```

And in the parent page you listen to these messages;

```
// Create IE + others compatible event handler
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

// Listen to message from child window
eventer(messageEvent, function(e) {

    var key = e.message ? "message" : "data";
    var message = e[key];

    if(message === "close-div") {
        $('div').hide();
    }

}, false);
```

Props of the code and explanation at; https://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe